# Checking for correctness of linked list functions

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So I create an executable using multiple C files and a header file, and I just have to create functions of different linked list manipulations. I'm trying to do it with generic data, there is a C test file that is suppose to test my functions. I don't really trust its correctness right now, so I'm wondering, here's three functions, I'm asking to see if there are any mistakes in these as I think there probably will be.
Any sort of insight would be helpful. I'm trying to create a working tester C file, but so far this part of my project is more important.

prints out the values in the sequence

```
#ifdef GENERIC
void seq_print(Seq seq, void (*print_func)(void *)){
        if(seq->top == NULL){
            printf("%s %c", "There is no data to print.", '\n');
            return;
        }
        Node * p = seq->top;
        while(p != NULL){
            print_func(p->data);
            p = p->next;
        }
}
#else
void seq_print(Seq seq){}
#endif
```

adds to front of a sequence

```
void seq_add_front(Seq seq, ETYPE val){
    printf("%s", "Running add_front \n");
    if(seq->top != NULL){
        Node * temp = seq->top;
        Node * newTop = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newTop->data = val;
        newTop->next = seq->top;
        seq->top = newTop;
    }else{
        seq->top = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        seq->top->data = val;
    }
    seq->size++;
}
```

deletes front of sequence

```
 ETYPE seq_del_front(Seq seq){
    if(seq->top != NULL){
        ETYPE ret = seq->top->data;
        Node * prevTop = seq->top;
        seq->top = seq->top->next;
        free(prevTop);
        return ret; 
    }
    return;
    seq->size--;
}
```

Comment: This question is more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If nothing else, you need to check the return value from `malloc` before using it.

Comment: Also: using pointers to pointers would simplify the code and _maybe_ even make it verifyable. See my answer here for a verifyable answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19407448/905902

Comment: where is your struct?